# Server on windows, clients on android

Tags: java, android, client

I am now trying to do a project which is, there will be a server on windows pc and there are some clients on android devices.The point is the server one should control the android devices.For example it choose a image or video, send them to the clients and the clients play or show them.Remember the clients should be control by the server.
   So could anyone tell me a proper way to do that, which protocol should i use, how do i send the files to the clients and how do the clients react? I am thinking of using java for the server and of course the client will use android application. 
   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might find Cloud to Device Messaging (c2dm) useful: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

In essence, c2dm allows a remote server to send an `Intent` to an Android app. The device-side app can then respond to that intent to take the requested action. Chrome2phone works this way to open web links on a target device. http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/

Comment: Thanks...I made some search running and c2dm is fitting to my project. But i think the example chrometophone is complicated. Could you suggest any other basic example for me?